# What is the notation $\textrm{LN}(X)$ in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What is the notation $\textrm{LN}(X)$ in linear algebra?

In the paper I am reading, for a given matrix $V$, the author decomposes matrix $A$ into $A^{\|}$ and $A^{\perp}$ such that

$AV = (A^{\perp} + A^{\|})V = A^{\perp}V + A^{\|}V = A^{\perp}V + \mathbf{0} = A^{\perp}V$,

and states that $A^{\perp} = A - \textrm{Projection}_{\textrm{LN}(V)}A$.

And I am not sure what $\textrm{LN}(V)$  exactly stands for.

Thank you,

Comment: What is the paper you're reading? They should explain that notation. But I guess it means $A=A^\parallel+A^\perp$ where $A^\parallel$ is the projection of $A$ onto the line spanned by $V$ (or some generalization of this notion from vectors to matrices). It might instead refer to a matrix logarithm, $\ln(X)=Y\implies X=\exp(Y)$, but I think that doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. what exactly do you mean by line spanned by $V$? do you mean the column space of the matrix $V$? Thank you,

Comment: One possible generalization is just the set of matrices $\{cV\mid c\in\mathbb R\}$. In that case, the matrices are being treated as vectors in an $n^2$-dimensional space, possibly with the Frobenius inner product.

Comment: Hello, it is $\textrm{LN}$

Comment: @mr_e_man to compute $A^{\perp}$, if I just use $A^{\perp}=A-\textrm{Projection}_{V}A$, would it make any difference?

Comment: No, the projection onto a vector is the same as the projection onto the line spanned by the vector.

Comment: emphasizing that this would be much easier to answer definitively and with confidence if you named the paper.

Comment: The name of the paper is "On Identifiability of Transformers" by Brunner et al., 2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe LN = [left nullspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#Left_null_space), also known as the cokernel.

---

Yes, the paper explicitly says:

> The (left) null space $\operatorname{LN}(T)$ of $T$ describes all
> vectors that are mapped to the zero vector by $T$:
> $$\operatorname{LN}(T) = \{\tilde{x}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times d_s}|\tilde{x}^T T = 0\}\tag4$$

Comment: What would be meant by the projection of a matrix onto a set of vectors?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. How can I find a left nullspace of a matrix $V$? I am generally unfamiliar with linear algebra. Is the left nullspace of matrix $V$ the same as the null space of the matrix $V^T$?

Comment: RobPratt: As noted at the Wikipedia page you linked, this is usually not called the kernel, but sometimes called the cokernel.
@jschnieder The Wikipedia link also tells you how to calculate the left nullspace.

Comment: @MarkS. yes, corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it didn't mean the projection of $A$ onto $LN(V)$, but rather the product of this projection (an operation on vectors, considered as a matrix) with $A$. ...Actually that's the same as projecting each of the columns of $A$, assuming the projection acts on column vectors rather than row vectors.