# How can I project matrix $A$ onto the space of the matrix $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I don't know if this question makes any sense, but how can I project matrix $A$ onto the space of the matrix $X$ (how can I compute $\textrm{Projection}_{X}A$)?

Thank you,

Comment: According to the answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3927999/472818), $LN(V)$ is not a matrix, but a set of vectors. So it looks like this question is on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question makes sense: with $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$, in the vector space $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$, you want to find the projection on $\mbox{Span}(X)$ (assuming that $X$ is not zero, otherwise it is obvious).

A good candidate is $P(M) = \frac{\mbox{Tr}(M^TX)}{\mbox{Tr}(X^TX)}X$. Then the image of $P$ is $\mbox{Span}(X)$ and for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$, you find $P(\lambda X) = \lambda X$.

Comment: Putting an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$ in my answer was not a really smart move, a field with finite characteristic may be problematic (I don't know about that case)

Comment: Hello, I can't really understand your answer. I am asking how to project $A$ onto the matrix $X$, but there is no $A$ in your explanation. also, does Span($X$) mean the column space of $X$?

Comment: So basically, to find $\textrm{Project}_{X}A$, do I simply compute $\frac{\textrm{Tr}(A^TX)}{\textrm{Tr}(X^TX)}X$, and the computed results would be the projection of $A$ onto $X$? Thank you,

Comment: Yes exactly, the projection of the matrix $A$ would be $P(A)$, as you wrote in your last message.
And by $\mbox{Span}(X)$ I meant $\{\lambda X, \ \lambda \in \mathbb{K}\}$